# Package marginfix swallows some margin notes

Tags: tufte, marginnote

I'm using `marginfix` together with the `tufte-book` class and I've noticed that sometimes margin notes simply disappear.  It rarely happens (the book is at about 500 pages now and I've seen it only two or three times so far), but if it happens I can't identify a reason *why* it happens.  What the cases mentioned seem to have in common is that they're always near the top of the page.  And that `marginfix` seems to be the culprit (although this package has otherwise been very helpful).

Here's one case where you can see the margin note symbol (in the third row) but not the margin note itself.  (And, no, it's not on the previous page.)

[shot1 http://nanook.agharta.de/shot1.png](http://nanook.agharta.de/shot1.png)

Here's the same page created from exactly the same source.  The only change was to comment out the usage of `marginfix`.  The margin note suddenly appears:

[shot2 http://nanook.agharta.de/shot2.png](http://nanook.agharta.de/shot2.png)

Any idea what I should try to figure out what causes this?

**EDIT:**

OK, I was finally able to create a MWE.  It took me quite some time because it's really hard to reproduce this.  I'm on Windows 10 using MikTeX 2.9.  Default paper format is A4 in case that matters.  The example is below.  If I run it like this, I see only one margin note.  If I comment out `\usepackage{marginfix}`, I see both margin notes...

```
\documentclass[nohyper, oneside, openany]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{marginfix}

\makeatletter
% Paragraph indentation and separation for normal text
\renewcommand{\@tufte@reset@par}{%
  \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0pc}%
  \setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{0pc}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pc}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex}%
}
\@tufte@reset@par

% Paragraph indentation and separation for marginal text
\renewcommand{\@tufte@margin@par}{%
  \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0.5pc}%
  \setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{0.5pc}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.5pc}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum\footnote{I am a footnote.

I'm the second paragraph of the footnote.}

\clearpage

\vspace*{332pt}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
\begin{align*}
  9652 &= 9 \cdot 1000 + 6 \cdot 100 + 5 \cdot 10 + 2 \cdot 1\\
  &= 9 \cdot (999 + 1) + 6 \cdot (99 + 1) + 5 \cdot (9 + 1) + 2 \cdot 1\\
  &= (9 + 6 + 5 + 2) + (9 \cdot 999 + 6 \cdot 99 + 5 \cdot 9)
\end{align*}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris\footnote{The
  following equation is wrong!}
\begin{equation}
  789\,234\,077 \cdot 457\,239\,331 = 360\,868\,851\,369\,882\,487
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using `marginfix` in combination with a tufte class?

Comment: I had quite a few margin notes which extended below the end of the main text.  `marginfix` takes care of that automatically.

Comment: I just opened an issue in the marginfix repo for this: https://github.com/shicks/marginfix/issues/15

Answer (score 5):

This was caused by a counter not being properly reset on new pages.  I've fixed it in version 1.2 [2020/05/06], uploaded to CTAN just now, or you can [download it from GitHub](https://github.com/shicks/marginfix/releases/tag/v1.2).